# birthday php calculator has strange effect

Tags: php

I'm using this code to calculate the birthday of my users:

```
            <?php
            $birthDate = $bday."/".$bmonth."/".$byear;
            $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
            $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], 
            $birthDate[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[2]));
            echo $age;
            ?>
```

When the input is the 23rd or 24th of any month in any year (for example, February 23rd, 1987) the age is -1 year off. It will say 25 years old instead of 26. I tested this for the late 80's in every month; it is always the 23rd and 24th.

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: That's an awful lot more complex than it needs to be. The second line basically undoes the first, and I don't even know what you're trying to do with that `date('md', date('U', mktime(...` mess.

Comment: `mktime` wants `hour,minute,second,month,day,year` (NOT `day,month,year`). But you're better of using something like [DateTime::diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) (The cause here is: the 23rd of 24h would result in November & December the year after, the 2 months after the month we are in now... the 25th is January again, and there's no 35th & 36th to increase it yet another year in a month after October)

Comment: I've successfully de-obfuscated the original code here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0w7G9Q I hope you agree how much more readable using intermediate variables and a proper `if` statement makes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$birth = new DateTime("$byear-$bmonth-$bday"); 
$today = new DateTime('today'); 
echo $birth->diff($today)->format('%y');
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't normally upvote a code-only answer, but this is so clear a piece of code, that the only thing missing is a link to the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Oh, also, a note that the choice of Year-Month-Day ordering is important, to avoid any other hiccups with American vs European conventions (D/M/Y vs M/D/Y).

Answer (score 1):

There are only two things you need to know to calculate someone's age: which year they were born, and whether they've had their birthday yet this year.

Since you have the date of birth as separate variables for day, month, and year, and are calculating the age "today", you could do something like this (note: [`idate()`](http://php.net/idate) is like `date()`, but returns an integer for a single aspect of the date, so is more efficient for calculations like this):

```
function calculate_age($byear, $bmonth, $bday)
{
    if (
        idate('m') < $bmonth
        ||
        (
            idate('m') == $bmonth
            &&
            idate('d') < $bday
        )
    )
    {
        // No birthday yet this year, so reduce age by 1
        return idate('Y') - $byear - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return idate('Y') - $byear;
    }
}
```

I think this is roughly the approach you were going for, but real `if`s rather than nested `?:` expressions make it much easier to see what's going on, and you don't need to mess around with multiple calls to `mktime` and `date`.